# ssis 2008 get package execution metadata

Tags: ssis

I need to collect meta data of a package execution includes execution start time, end time, number of rows (the package is a simple database view to csv file data flow). And I will need to generate a file include these information. I would prefer get this done along with the package execution. Is there some clever way to do this?

Update, I can do it in SSIS 2012 as well. So whatever easiest.

Comment: Program your package to collect and output this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 easy ways:

1) Populate the output file as just another destination in your data flow task.

- number of rows:
  that's what the **Row Count** transformation is for
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141136(v=sql.110).aspx
- execution start time:
  **Audit** transformation gets this and some other useful info
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141150(v=sql.110).aspx
- end time:
  it's not really the end time yet, but you can use the current time returned by `GETDATE()` expression in a Derived Column transformation.

2) Use SSIS Logging:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms140246(v=sql.110).aspx

It's not so straightforward for row count and other data details, but StartTime/EndTime are easy.
Text file is one of the Log provider options there.

Comment: Not exactly what I want but helpful, thanks. In the end I did it ssis 12, there is a expression task, I put one before the data flow another one after it and in each task assign start time  and end time (two variables) to system time. So that I know the start/end time for the data extraction. And yes your Row Count transformation gets me the row count (put in data flow). Then in another data flow, use a script component as source and with columns start/end time, row count etc, followed by a derived column where I assign the columns with value from the variables, finally output to a text file.